# Python modules confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I feel a bit confused with how python modules work when I started looking at PyMySQL repository, see here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL?files=1

1) Why is there no pymysql.py file because it is imported like: import pymysql? Isnt it required to have such a file?

2) I cannot find the method connect, used like: pymysql.connect(...), anywhere. Is it possible to rename exported methods somehow?

Comment: if you want to use the module just use ` pip install PyMySQL` in your project directory and it will be alright.

Comment: A file is not a module. Executing the code in `foo.py` is *one* way to create a module named `foo`. Another way is to execute the code in `foo/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a directory `pymysql` there. A directory can also be imported as a module*, with the advantage that it can contain *submodules*.  Classically, there's a `__init__.py` file in the directory that controls what's in the top-level `pymysql.*` namespace.

So, the `connect` method you're missing will either be defined directly in `pymysql/__init__.py`, or defined in one of its siblings in that directory, and then imported from there by `pymysql/__init__.py`.

*Strictly speaking, a directory that you `import` like a module is really called a "package". I like to avoid that term—it's potentially confusing because the term is overloaded: what you install with `pip` is also called a "package" in sense 2, and that might actually contain multiple "packages" in sense 1.

See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) and [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: I believe `__init__.py` is required, even if it's empty.

Comment: @jordanm It used to be—not strictly, since Python 3.3

Comment: Thanks, but could you also elaborate on the connect method, and why i cannot find it? (Not Connection.connect)